# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for MIT Opencourse Assignment

Tags: python

Tried to attempt question on MIT OpenCourseware Sc 6.00. 
The question is on how to find combination of McNuggets with 6, 9, 20 packs with total number given.
Currently my code is:

```
def Mac ():
    totalnumber = int (input('Enter total number of McNuggets'))
    num20,num6,num9= solve2(totalnumber)

def solve2(numtotal): #define a new function to find and print multiple answers
    solutionfound = False # set up a variable to check if the solution is found
    for num20 in range (0,numtotal//20 + 1):
        for num9 in range (0,numtotal//9 +1):
            num6 = (numtotal-num20*20-num9*9)//6
            if num6 > 0:
                checknum = num20*20+num9*9+num6*6
                if checknum == numtotal:
                    print ('The number of 6-pack is', num6)
                    print ('The number of 9-pack is', num9)
                    print ('The number of 20-pack is', num20)
                    solutionfound = True # change the initial variable to True
    if not solutionfound:
        print ('There is no solution')
```

However, when running this code, it always display:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Which line in your code is raising the exception?

Comment: `solve2` returns `None`, python is trying to unpack it.

Comment: @Nurzhan It is not recommended to modify whitespaces in Python code in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The function `solve2()` does not returns any value, so its return value is `None` and you are trying to iterate that by doing `num20,num6,num9= solve2(totalnumber)`. So this part of your code raises `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Looking at your code I can't decide from where to return the values, so wherever you want to return values, just use `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def Mac ():
    totalnumber = int (input('Enter total number of McNuggets: '))
    num20,num6,num9 = solve2(totalnumber)

def solve2(numtotal): #define a new function to find and print multiple answers
    solutionfound = False # set up a variable to check if the solution is found
    for num20 in range (0,numtotal//20 + 1):
        for num9 in range (0,numtotal//9 +1):
            num6 = (numtotal-num20*20-num9*9)//6
            if num6 > 0:
              checknum = num20*20+num9*9+num6*6
              if checknum == numtotal:
                  print ('The number of 6-pack is', num6)
                  print ('The number of 9-pack is', num9)
                  print ('The number of 20-pack is', num20)
                  solutionfound = True # change the initial variable to True
                  return (num6, num9, num20)
    if not solutionfound:
        print ('There is no solution')
        return (None, None, None)

Mac()
```

As it was correctly noted  you need to return value from you method solve2.